# Creating a MIDI file from an AKKeyboardView

Tags: ios, audiokit

Currently I am using an `AKKeyboardView` to connect essentially to the `AKRhodesPiano` object, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to generate a MIDI file from this?

I see the `AKKeyboardView` has the `noteOn` and `noteOff` functions, which does produce the `MIDINoteNumber` but I can't find anywhere else in the AudioKit library to really take this input and generate a MIDI file, even if only just a simple one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to run an AKSequencer in the background (maybe with a metronome track).  Make an additional track that you will record onto.  Also set the length to be as long as you will need for the recording.

When you get a noteOn message from the keyboard, you can check the sequencer's `currentPosition` and record this into a dictionary.  When you get the matching pitch's noteOff message, again check the `currentPosition`.  Use the difference between these two times to get the duration and add a note to your recording track on the sequencer:

```
myRecordingTrack.add(noteNumber: noteNumber,
              velocity: 127,
              position: timeAtNoteOn,
              duration: timeAtNoteOff - timeAtNoteOn,
              channel: 0)
```

Then you could easily use `AKSequencer`'s `genData()` to create a MIDI file (possibly either deleting the metronome track, or copying the recorded track to a new `AKSequencer` instance).

Check out the SequencerDemo for setting up `AKSequencer` and building sequences and MIDIFileEditAndSync (both in the iOS Example folder in the AudioKit repo) for an example of writing `AKSequencer` to a MIDI file.