# Swift - AudioKit AKMidi to AKSequencer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I currently have an application which uses an AKKeyboard to create sounds using an Oscillator. Whenever the keyboard is played I get the MIDI data also. What I would like to do is create an AKSequence from the MIDI data I receive.

Any advice or pointers will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is a partial amount of my code:

```
var bank = AKOscillatorBank()
var midi: AKMIDI!
let sequencer = AKSequencer()
let sequenceLength = AKDuration(beats: 8.0)

func configureBank() {
    AudioKit.output = bank

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit couldn't be started")
    }

    midi = AudioKit.midi
    midi.addListener(self)
    midi.openInput()
}

// AKKeyboard Protocol methods
func noteOn(note: MIDINoteNumber) {
    let event = AKMIDIEvent(noteOn: note, velocity: 80, channel: 5)
    midi.sendEvent(event)
    bank.play(noteNumber: note, velocity: 100)
}

func noteOff(note: MIDINoteNumber) {
    let event = AKMIDIEvent(noteOff: note, velocity: 0, channel: 5)
    midi.sendEvent(event)
    bank.stop(noteNumber: note)
}

// AKMIDIListener Protocol methods..
func receivedMIDINoteOff(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
    print("ReceivedMIDINoteOff: \(noteNumber), velocity: \(velocity), channel: \(channel)")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to build the sequence directly from the AKMIDIEvents. Just query the sequence's currentPosition when you call AKKeyboardView's noteOn and noteOff methods and programmatically add events to a sequencer track based on this.

The process is basically identical to this (minus the final step, of course): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071028/2717159

Edit - To get the noteOn and noteOff times, and duration:

```
// store notes and times in a dictionary:
var noteDict = [MIDINoteNumber: MIDITimeStamp]()

// when you get a noteOn, note the time
noteDict[currentMIDINote] = seq.currentPosition.beats

// when you get a noteOff
let endTime = seq.currentPosition.beats
if let startTime = noteDict[currentMIDINote] {
    let durationInBeats = endTime - startTime
    // use the startTime, duration and currentMIDINote to add event to track
    noteDict[currentMIDINote] = nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that reference definitely helps. Can you explain how I could could calculate the timeAtNoteOn & timeAtNoteOff with the currentPosition? I'm stuck on that now.

Comment: Also when I want to play the sequencer to hear all the MIDI would I only have one sequencer or two? I ask of this because when I create the sequencer I have to play it to see the current position, the desire is to record the MIDI from the AKKeyboard and play it back to the user on a click of a button.

Comment: Added code re your first comment.  Regarding the second, you could do it with only one sequencer.  Just set the output of the track to which you are writing the events to an AKCallbackInstrument which triggers your external MIDI events (as you do in the AKKeyboardDelegate above). The Readme for https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/iOS/AudiobusMIDISender gives an example of setting this up.  So AKKeyboardDelegate methods trigger live events, and the sequencer track triggers the recorded ones.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, you really are a AudioKit King. I'm most likely going to open another question about something else maybe to do with Audiobus, but for now I have an issue (well at least I think it's an issue). When I query the currentPosition.beats I always receive 0.0.

Comment: Also how would I convert MIDITimestamp to AKDuration?

Comment: MIDITimeStamp is just a typealias for Double, giving you the position in beats.  So, AKDuration(beats: myMIDITimeStamp)

Comment: Ok that works, thank you. So is receiving 0.0 normal?

Comment: When are you checking the currentPosition? If you haven't started playback, it should be at 0.0 - otherwise it should give you the current playback position.  If you continue having a problem, perhaps post a new question here, with some sample code.

Comment: I start the sequence before I check the currentPosition, strangely it was working prior to me making a few changes (edit I just checked, the bug has fixed itself). Also is there any reason for me actually using Audiobus or did you just say check the readme for examples of code usage?

Comment: Also is it default behaviour for the callback to continue functioning even when nothing is going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179457/discussion-between-fuad-adetoro-and-c-booth).